# grep not matching exact string

Tags: grep

I'm a bit troubled by `grep` not behaving as expected.
I'm trying to extract hosts from a sort of dictionary, structured like `OLD_HOST_NAME;NEW_HOST_NAME`, and some of them have the same prefix, like "HOST-1-2".
I want to only match "HOST-1-2", but independently from which option I pass to grep, it keeps returning all the strings with the same prefix instead of matching only the exact string, i.e.:

```
grep -F "HOST-1-2" dict.txt
HOST-1-2-3;NEW_HOST-1-2-3
HOST-1-2-4;NEW_HOST-1-2-4
HOST-1-2-5;NEW_HOST-1-2-5
```

I tried several options, like `grep -w "HOST-1-2"`, `grep -e '\HOST-1-2\b'`, `grep -e '\HOST-1-2\b'`, `grep -Po "\bHOST-1-2\b"` (that actually match what I want, but it does it for all occurrences of the substring so it's still not working), tried mixing them, but at the end of the day I'm still not getting what I need.

Any idea on how to achieve what I want, in order for grepping only "HOST-1-2" without all the other partial matches?

**EDIT:**
Sorry to not have specified more clearly, the dictionary sample is the one I already shown as result of the wrong substring matching crep:

```
old_host;new_host
SERVER-1;NEW_SERVER-1
HOST-1-2-3;NEW_HOST-1-2-3
HOST-1-2-4;NEW_HOST-1-2-4
HOST-1-2-5;NEW_HOST-1-2-5
```

I already stated what I want to achieve though:

> in order for grepping only "HOST-1-2" without all the other partial
> matches

Comment: `\b` won't help, because there's a word boundary between `2` and `-`.

Comment: please update the question with a sample of data from `dict.txt` and the desired output

Comment: So, do you want any of the sample data lines selected?  Or do you only want the line (not shown) starting `HOST-1-2;` (which would be `grep -e '^HOST-1-2;'`)?  Could you have lines like `HOST-1-2-234;HOST-1-2` to confuse things?  Would you want that selected?  What about `HOST-1-2-324;HOST-1-2-99`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -o` to print only the matching part of the lines and add a word boundary after the `2` and before the `H`

```
grep -o '\<HOST-1-2\>' ./dict.txt
```

Output

```
HOST-1-2
HOST-1-2
HOST-1-2
```

If you only want to print the first matches:

```
grep -oP '^.*?\b\KHOST-1-2\b' ./dict.txt
```

Comment: Hi, both your solution and @anubhava worked fine to exclude partial matches, but what I needed in a second moment was also to only match a part of the result, specifically the "old_host" bit, so your second part of the answer (the `grep -oP`) anticipated my following question :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
grep -E '(^|;)HOST-1-2(;|$)' file
```

Which means:

- `-E`: Enable extended regex mode
- `(^|;)`: Match start or `;`
- `HOST-1-2`: Match `HOST-1-2`
- `(;|$)`: Match `;` or end